# Why drupal need hidden option in comment settings of content types?

Tags: comments

In content type setting in drupal, we have tab comment setting .The comment setting on future content of this type will default to:

- **Hidden:** No comments are allowed, and past comments are hidden.
- Closed: No comments are allowed, but any past comments remain visible.
- Open: Any future content of this type is open to new comments.

**Why do we need HIDDEN option?** It  does not make sense in content type setting . If we set this option - in any new nodes that will be created next  - comment will be closed.

This option has sense only in particular material, if it has comments.

Please explain me why this option need in content type settings?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

> This option has sense only in particular material, if it has comments.

Precisely. So you should use this option when a content type has comments that you don't want to delete, but don't want to allow people to see either permanently or temporarily.

If you don't need that option, you don't need to use it. But its existence makes perfect sense.

Comment: This option work only for new materias. Only!

Comment: Yep that's correct. If you want new content of a certain content type to have its comments hidden, you use this option. Is anything still unclear? Is it the _and past comments are hidden._ bit that's causing confusion? If so I agree that phrasing is a little redundant, but it doesn't mean the option itself is redundant

Answer (score 0):

This option(if it set in content type settings) work only for new materias. Only!
So when a create node, in comment settings of this node, will be option CLOSE. Because no comments were added.
And only if I add some comments for it, status HIde for comments were added. ( But in order to add this some comments, I will have to change the comment option to OPEN )
So this option does not make sense in content type setting